# Best way to render a parent fields and childrens fields in a unique form in django?

Tags: django, forms, orm

The use case is the following one

I have a parent class: Parent with some basic fields (name, description)
I have several children classes Child1,Child2,Child3 (with some extra fields)

I would like to display a form that will contain:
- the fields of Parent Model
- a dropdown with possibles values: Child1,Child2,Child3
- then depending on selected value, display Child1 model fields, or child2 model fields,etc...

The best will be also to be able to create this in the django admin site.

So I can create a CRUD, click on Add button display this "unique" form.
Then in the list view I can see elements of type Child1 or Child2, Child3,etc...

Example:

```
class Trigger(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=64, default='*')
    ....

class CRONTrigger(Trigger):
     minute = models.CharField(_('minute'), max_length=64, default='*')
     hour = models.CharField(_('hour'), max_length=64, default='*')
     ...

 class EventTrigger(Trigger):
     event_name = models.CharField(_('minute'), max_length=64, default='*')
     ....
```

What I want is 
127.0.0.1:8090/admin/product/trigger/add/
to return

```
name
select CRON or Event
if cron: minute,hours,...
if event: event_name,...
```

In other words
I want 
127.0.0.1:8090/admin/product/trigger/add/

to return the forms of 
127.0.0.1:8090/admin/product/crontrigger/add/
127.0.0.1:8090/admin/product/eventtrigger/add/

or the same page.

**EDIT**

Finally I found the beginning of a solution:
/admin/production/trigger/add/

```
class TriggerAdmin(SynapsAdmin):  
    inlines = [CronTriggerInline,ThresholdAdminInline]

class ThresholdAdminInline(admin.StackedInline):
     model = ThresholdTrigger
     extra = 1

class CronTriggerInline(admin.StackedInline):
     model = CRONTrigger
     extra = 1
```

Now with some javascript in the admin override to hide/show subform. Just need to avoid create of both cron and threshold object

Comment: It's definitely doable, but might not be that straight forward. Do you think it would be OK for them to select from a dropdown first to choose which child form they want? In that case, you can load the whole form instead of partially parent and partially child.

Comment: hello, Yes this is in fact what I am doing. I just added a "first screen to select try them load the child form page after that. But in this case I want all on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is:

create a modelchoicefield in the form and set the queryset to Child.objects.none()

Then at the bottom of the form add something to the effect of:

```
def __init__(self, your_queryset):
    super(ParentForm, self).__init__()
    self.fields['child'].queryset = your_queryset
```

Then you can do whatever you need by referencing the template tag's ID and get the selected child.

Answer (score 0):

Django Admin by default doesn't support such advanced feature to make forms fields being displaced dynamically based on other field values, but in order to do that you need to extend the Admin template and use Jquery:

1. Django use old version of jquery, but you can update or add other js script by adding them to the meta class Media in **admin.py**:

```js
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('field1', 'field2')

        class Media:
            js = (
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
                'js/myscript.js',     
                'app/js/myscript.js',                 )

    admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

2. the next step is to extend the Admin template which is the hard part:
   in order to modify template for specific App you have to respect the followin scructure:

```js
my_project
     |-- my_project/
     |-- myapp1/
     |-- myapp2/
     |-- templates/
          |-- admin/
              |-- myapp1/
                  |-- *.html
              |-- myapp2/
                  |-- *.html
```

the list of html file under the app should have the same name as the default admin html file names. Check [Extending Django’s Admin Interface](http://book.huihoo.com/django/en/1.0/chapter17/index.html) to have idea of the file names and the basis to extend them.

Comment: Hello,
Yes I know about admin override no problem with that. I updated my question to better explain my need

Comment: Yes I read your question, as I explained you need to override **admin/change_form.html** diplaying all the forms, make the Parent form visible and making the others invisible using `.hide()` the jequery method, then based on your choices use jquery **event listener** to display one of the hidden form using `.show()`